# PHP class Textile is slow and causes timeout

Tags: php, optimization, textile

I'm using the textile class from here: http://textile.thresholdstate.com/ (site is currently unavailable), which works well with less than 20,000 characters. Any more causes PHP to timeout with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded ...
```

I'm thinking this is probably not a really efficient markup parser?

1. Can anyone suggest any alternatives to this textile class?
2. Has anyone refactored the code and made improvements on the class?
3. What are some general PHP optimizations (with loops etc) that i could try (or look for) to improve the speed of my code?

**Update**

Thanks for the suggestion of increasing the php time limit, I've bumped it up a bit.

However page load of 1 minute is terrible. So i kept digging and found the following site has a list of Textile versions, starting from 2003 to Dec 2012: http://txstyle.org/article/36/textile-versions

It turns out i was using the textile class from 2006! It's come a long way since then and the latest version seems to run a lot faster. Specifically, there seems to be an improvement in the "doBr" function that prevents my test from timing out.

Comment: "optimizations (with loops etc) that i could try" - Well that depends on what your code looks like. Please post it if you need help optimizing it.

Comment: Good call. It's quite a large class to post into stack overflow though. Was hoping for some cheap and quick pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Set your PHP execution time to more than 30 seconds in php.ini

This could be easily increased on most shared webhostings. just write them an email, if it couldn't be done via their cpanel or admin already by yourself.

Comment: Ok, maybe i can do that. But then again, I'd prefer to use a better class, or figure out how to optimize the code. Is it common for sites to have an increased execution time to more than 30 seconds?

Comment: Why not. It's like the PHP memory limit. Most of the webhosting companies have allocated less than 48MB (to save the resources within the server you are on) when e.g. a Drupal website with some (not to many modules) need about 60MB. Just ask them to go to increase to 60 sec and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Set php execution time limit to no time limit with:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```